# Using Alamofire with Yelp Search API

Tags: swift, oauth, alamofire, yelp

Is it possible to use Alamofire with the Yelp Search API? If so, how do you generate the OAuth signature? Here's a snippet of the code I'm trying to make work. Thanks in advance.

```
func searchForBusinessesByLocation(term: String, location: String) {
        Alamofire.request(Method.GET, NSURL(string: "http://\(self.api_host)\(self.search_path)")!, parameters: ["term":self.searchTerm, "location":self.searchLocation,"limit":self.search_limit, "oauth_consumer_key":self.CONSUMER_KEY, "oauth_token":self.TOKEN, "oauth_signature_method":self.SIGNATURE_METHOD, "oauth_signature":self.SIGNATURE, "oauth_timestamp":self.timestamp(), "oauth_nonce":self.NONCE]).responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, completionHandler: {(_,_,result, error) in
            if(result != nil) {
                println("result \(result)")
            }
            else {
                println("no result")
            }
            if(error != nil) {
                println("error \(error)")
            }
            else {
                println("no error")
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating the OAuth signature is a bit long and complex to write into an SO answer, I'd suggest you have a look at [this article](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures) describing how to do it.

Good luck!